# ReferenceError- crossfilter is not defined

Tags: javascript, d3.js, crossfilter

After we updated our d3, dc and crossfilter js files to current, we are getting: crossfilter is not defined error on dc.js (1.7.5) line-

this.dc = _dc(d3, crossfilter);

Here's how the html is coded:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script  src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<script  src="https://d3js.org/d3-time.v1.min.js"></script>
<script  src="https://d3js.org/d3-time-format.v2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/1.7.5/dc.js">   </script> 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>    
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crossfilter/1.3.12/crossfilter.js"></script>   

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/url.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/combodate.js"></script>
```

Not sure if the upgrades now need another js file?  The prior crossfilter.js we used was 1.3.11 and the dc file we used was dc.min.js dc2.0.0-beta.14.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Did you change the order in which you load the scripts? You have dc.js being loaded before crossfilter.

Comment: I just made the change you suggested @Jecoms and now I am getting - TypeError - d3.time is undefined on dc.js line -  dc.dateFormat = d3.time.format("%m/%d/%Y");  I think the d3 function is now d3.timeFormat, not d3.time.format.

Comment: I changed the d3 to-  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.0.0/d3.js"></script> and reran and now get error - chart.data() is not a function in my index.js .   [servicePieChart, operationPieChart, timeDetailsChart].forEach(function (chart, i) {
   
    var chartData = chart.data();

Comment: I don't know that the order you include the scripts is actually a guarantee that they load in that order. You may want to consider a script loader / build system like WebPack.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use d3 version 3, not version 4 with dc.js, and you need to load the scripts in the right order. d3.js and Crossfilter need to load before dc.js.

Comment: after I create a pieChart  - var servicePieChart = dc.pieChart("#service-pie-chart");   the __dc_Flag__ now comes back as true where before it came back as 1.  I have another pieChart that comes back now as true too for __dc__Flag where before it came back as 2.  So I think this is what's causing the error - chart.Data() is not a function.   Any ideas how to correct this?  Thanks!

Comment: This seems like a separate question? I'd suggest putting together an example and creating a new question if your original issue is resolved. I'm not understanding the problem described in the comment.

Comment: Sorry.  I put the js's in order like you suggested and 
I changed the d3 to- <script src="cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.0.0/d3.js"></…; and reran and now get error - chart.data() is not a function in my index.js . [servicePieChart, operationPieChart, timeDetailsChart].forEach(function (chart, i) { var chartData = chart.data();   The comment I just put above pertains to this error - chart.data() is not a function.

Comment: I think you should open a separate question for this. It's a different issue. *But*, don't use d3 3.0.0. That is extremely old. Use the latest version in the 3.x chain. I think that's https://cdnjs.com/libraries/d3/3.5.17